# Restore AWS S3 Glacier Binary but the file size is 0 bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, archive

I don't understand why after I perform an S3 with glacier restore, then change the storage class back to standard, the binary is 0 bytes?  As if the restore didn't work at all.

Do binaries have to be in Glacier for 48 hours before they can be restored?

**Example Pics:**

[Before archiving to glacier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKLVe.png)

[After restore and update to storage class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDEv3.png)

Comment: Generally to ask a good question you should say what your problem is  - for example I am trying to do X and this happens. Also generally stackoverflow is for programming questions but this sounds to me like you are trying to do something in AWS via their configuration UI - maybe try asking on https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The object size never changes, regardless of the storage class or restore status.  Something else, unrelated, happened to this object.  If you don't have access logs enabled for the bucket, you might want to enable those so you can identify what's really going on.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, you are right.  It was an improper putObject using the SDK that was blowing away the binary.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

When I updated the storage class I performed a bad putObject which blew the binary away.  Michael-sqlbot informed me that the size should never change when updating an object's storage class. Lesson learned...